# Displaying a multidimensional array without document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Currently, I have a two by two array: `let gameBoard = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]` I want to print this array on my webpage. I have done so by using document.write().

```
function updateScreen(){
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<4; j++){
            document.write('<span>' + gameBoard[i][j] + '&emsp;</span>')
        }
        document.write("<br><br>")
    }
}
```

This displays the array in a 2x2 matrix on a webpage like this:

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

That is the layout that I want. However, the document.write() function deletes all my existing HTML code. How do I display the array on my original webpage? Also, it needs to be displayed in way that I can style it with CSS.

Comment: you can target an element if you creata a div with id target then you can do var loop = ''; loop+= '<span>' + gameBoard[i][j] + '&emsp;</span>'; document.getElementById('target).innerHTML = loop

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to populate a table with it. Since you had a grid of data, this was a possible way to make sense of it.

```js
let gameBoard = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
  ['+', '*', '@', '&'],
  ['Z', 'Y', 'X', 'W']
];

function updateScreen() {
  let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3],
    table = document.querySelector('table');
  arr.forEach(x => {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    arr.forEach(y => row.insertCell(y).appendChild(document.createTextNode(gameBoard[x][y])))
  })
}

updateScreen();
```

```css
.board {
  border-collapse : separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.board td {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align:center;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  border-radius:4px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table class='board'></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that matches your use of `span`s, and utilizes the [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) object, so as to reduce the number of reflows.

```
<div id="gameBoard"></div>
<script>
    var gameBoard = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
    function updateScreen()
    {
        let rows = gameBoard.length;
        let cols = gameBoard[0].length; // assumes at least the 0th index is set
        let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
        let linebreak = document.createElement('br');

        for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                let cell = document.createElement('span');
                    cell.innerText = gameBoard[i][j];
                fragment.append(cell, "&nbsp;");
            }

            fragment.append(linebreak.cloneNode(), linebreak.cloneNode());
        }

        document.getElementById('gameBoard').appendChild(fragment);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting answer. I've never used DocumentFragment() before. upvoted

Comment: @Kinglish Thank you. It's actual improvement in performance is highly debated, but it is still a very "proper" solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Append to the body's innerHTML:

```js
function updateScreen(){
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<4; j++){
            document.body.innerHTML+='<span>' + gameBoard[i][j] + '&emsp;</span>';
        }
        document.body.innerHTML+="<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways how Javascript can create an output.

document.write() deletes all previous concent. There is a better one:

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "hey I am a cool text";
</script>
```

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp